# FlowPanel Vertical Scroll

Tags: c#, flowpanel

I have a flowpanel that I'm dynamically adding usercontrols to.  I want it to keep adding them and use a vertical scroll bar.  It instead wraps them to the top and places a horizontal scroll bar.  I'm sure I'm just missing something, but how do I get it to do vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out what I did.  I had the flow direction set to TopDown, it needed to be set to LeftRight.

Sometimes I feel like a moron.

Comment: To me, TopDown sounds like it would be what you want. Maybe flowdirection means something else to the designer of the flowpanel.

Comment: I agree with Joe,  the name of that attribute is confusing

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable scroll write this: `flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;`